# many instances of wysihtml5 - append text

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

I have few instances od wysihtml5 on one page.

I want to insert into one of this instances text, using

```
editor.setValue(text, true);
```

and of course this text is inserted into the last instance.

But how to insert text into first instance ?

About instances, i mean:

- this occur as first textarea in html, so it is first istance
 - this is the last one

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the appropriate editor and then setValue.

You can get the editor of a textArea with:

```
var appropriateEditor = $("#textAreaId").data("wysihtml5").editor;
```

Now, you can set the text:

```
appropriateEditor.setValue(text, true);
```

Hope it helps.